# optimize my VBA code, so it runs faster / stock prices computations

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

I need to optimize my code, so it runs faster. There is only 12 000 computations in it. I have around 6 000 rows in my worksheet, and I need to count rate of return in one column and logarithmic rate of return in the other.

The problem is that, when I do these counting using Excel formulas, it takes like 2-3 sec per column, so rate of return for 6 000 rows is counted in 2 sec and the same with logarithmic rate of return in second column.
But my code takes 60 seconds to run.
How is that even possible? I was sure VBA computing will be much faster than that.

```
Sub Normal_Return_Rate()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim current_price As Single
  Dim previous_price As Single
  Dim a_cell As Range
  Dim b_cell As Range
  Dim vba_cell As Range
  Dim row As Long
  Dim b_col As Integer
  Dim vba_col As Integer
  Dim last_row As Long

  Dim start As Double
  Dim finish As Double
  Dim total_time As Double

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  start = Timer                   ' remember time when macro starts.


  Set ws = Workbooks("lista_spolek_gpw.xlsm").Worksheets("MBank_Statsy")
  last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  row = 3
  Set a_cell = ws.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="LOW", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  Set b_cell = ws.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="CLOSE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
  Set vba_cell = ws.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="VBA code" & Chr(10) & "result", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

  b_col = b_cell.Column
  vba_col = vba_cell.Column
  ws.Cells(row, b_col).Activate

  With ws.Range("M3:N" & last_row)                 
                  ' previous version:   ws.Range("M2:N" & Rows.Count)
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
       .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
       .WrapText = False
       .NumberFormat = "00.00%"
       .Orientation = 0
       .AddIndent = False
       .IndentLevel = 0
       .ShrinkToFit = False
       .ReadingOrder = xlContext
       .MergeCells = False
       .ColumnWidth = 13
  End With


   With ws
       Do While Cells(row, b_col) <> ""
          current_price = ActiveCell.Value
          previous_price = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
          ws.Cells(row, vba_col) = Round(current_price / previous_price - 1, 4)
          ws.Cells(row, 14) = Log(current_price / previous_price)
          row = row + 1
          ws.Cells(row, b_col).Activate
       Loop
   End With

 finish = Timer
 total_time = Round(finish - start, 3)       ' Calculate total time.
 MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & total_time & " seconds", vbInformation
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Any piece of advice which will make this code run faster is highly appreciated. I'm just the beginner in VBA.**

This is how the sheet looks like - its stock quotes sheet.
The computations are using values from "CLOSE" column.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The multiple accesses to your worksheet slow down your code.  Better would be to read all the data into a VBA variant array (one step:  `myArray = myRange` (after you define `myRange`). And then do your calculations in the VBA array.  Then write it back to the worksheet (again, one step: `myRange = myArray`).  Format everything after you've got all the data back on the worksheet in one series and not in the calc loop. This may speed your calculations 10 fold.  See also Chip Pearsons article on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Exactly what @RonRosenfeld said. If you dont want to put the effort in that you can turn `Application.Calculation =xlCalculationManual` if you havent done that. This will speed up your code too

Comment: is this something different then reading all the data into a VBA variant array, suggested by @Ron Rosenfeld ? Or should I do both of this operations together? I'm in the process of reading this article Ron Rosenfeld suggested. I'm going to make these changes, because I want to learn how to write efficient code. Another thing bothers me - why all the help I'm getting is provided in the form of comments and not answers to the question. When the question is not answered it's highly probable it'll be deleted in some time, and that's what I'd like to avoid. These questions are my problems memory.

Comment: Comments are made when they do not provide complete answers, or require more information to develop a complete answer.  I see that @PalimPalim implemented a variation of my suggestion in code, but you'll be better served by developing your own implementation.  Also, there is no restriction on answering your own question, and then marking it as the answer. But Slai did provide a useful link.

Comment: how can I see/peak inside that array I've created. I need to check if I assigned the values correctly. I've written: `last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row` then `b_col = b_cell.Column` then `close_array = ws.Range(Cells(2, b_col), Cells(last_row, b_col))`  Is t good??   But tell me How can see what values are inside the array??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I built a simplified version of your code and got an almost identical runtime. [image]

Next I updated this simplified version to work with arrays. It is substantially faster.
[image]

My Code uses some hardcoded values, but my goal was not to find the solution for you but to get a solution which helps you write the code yourself. Hope it helps.

```
Sub Normal_Return_Rate_fast()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim last_row As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim b_col As Integer
Dim arr As Variant
Dim res() As Double



Application.ScreenUpdating = False
start = Timer

Set ws = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
last_row = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
row = 2
b_col = 1

arr = Range("A2:A6000").Value
size_x = last_row - row + 1
ReDim res(size_x, 2) As Double
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
    res(i - 2, 0) = Round(arr(i, 1) / arr(i - 1, 1) - 1, 4)
    res(i - 2, 1) = Log(arr(i, 1) / arr(i - 1, 1))
Next i

Range("B3:C6000").Value = res

finish = Timer
total_time = Round(finish - start, 3)       ' Calculate total time.
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & total_time & " seconds", vbInformation
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is how my "TestWorkbook" looks like.

[image]

Just 1 to 5999 in column A.

Comment: Can U explain to me what "res" and "size_x" variables represent?

Comment: res is an empty array of doubles in which i am putting calculation results. res as results

Comment: Can we assign a "size_x" variable something like that: `size_x = last_row - 1`.  Isn't it the header row we subtract from the PX_Last dataset?

Comment: size_x is the first dimension of the array aka the number of rows, so it can be anything which can be a number of rows. yes that would work.

Comment: why the "arr" array is declared as Variant, while the "res()" array is declared as Double?  Do I need to have first the input array and the second output array?

Comment: no you could change the code to have both in the same array. res is double since it only holds doubles. arr is variant because in a range there also could be strings. but all this is up to you, how you like to implement it. just the way of how i do it normally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145289/discussion-between-michal-roesler-and-palimpalim).